# What word will fit?

Tags: word

I hope you have a large vocab because here's a question where you'll need only one word.

> Andy a waiter,  didn't _____ that what was in the drink was_____and
>   that without it, the drink would have  _____ to the customers

Can you use only one word in three different forms to fill in the blanks?

Edit:

> I used only one word and added spaces to make it a different word.
>  Example: notable, not able, no table.

If it means anything, the words made can be found in a Websters Dictionary, but it shouldn't help much.

Comment: Sorry, but you are not using one word in three different forms.  You are using different words that can be combined to make the same word.  Additionally, one of the words you are using in a grammatically incorrect way.

Comment: @Kevin I'm open to suggestions on how I should use it.  Tice is not a common word, so had to figure out how I was supposed to use it.  But seriously if you know how to make it correct I'd love to make it better

Comment: There aren't many references to _tice_; none of the online dictionaries I'd normally use (OED, Chambers, Merriam-Webster) have it. The few references I could find have _tice_ as a verb, an old form of _entice_, so "no tice" is awkward, as enticing as it may be to use it for this puzzle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is :

> notice

Because :

> Andy a waiter, didn't **notice** that what was in the drink was **not ice** and that without it, the drink would have **no tice** to the customers.

Comment: Actually your overall answer is correct! The last blank is wrong though

Comment: Oh, nice! I was thinking about `no tice`, but I don't think tice is a real word.

Comment: @IAmInPLS: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tice

Comment: @Marius Yes, I saw that, but it doesn't seem to make sense with the sentence, does it?

Comment: I agree, It's kind of forced, but it might fit.

Comment: I do write these myself and I might not have the best logic, or riddle base, so I couldn't think of something better to make  it fit

Comment: So this is `no tice` for good?

Comment: Yes, It is what I thought when I wrote it

Comment: edited it a little not sure if it helps